# Expecting unsat instad of sat in Z3

Tags: z3, smt, formal-verification

I am facing a situation in which I am expecting to get UNSAT from Z3, but I'm getting SAT instead.

Here are the 4 constraints I believe are given to Z3:

**1.** `(i = 0) ==> (forall j: 0 <= j < n ==> a[j] = b[j])`

**2.** `(i = 1) ==> (exists j: 0 <= j < n ==> a[j] != b[j])`

**3.** `i = 0`

**4.** `a[0] != b[0]`

This should be obviously UNSAT. Because according to 1 and 3, we conclude that the array's `a` and `b` should be equal in every index. Thus `a[0]` can't be not-equal to `b[0]`.

Here is the output's of `Z3_ast_to_string(...)` (I'm using the C API) for each constraint mentioned above:

**1.**

```
(let ((a!1 (concat (select memcmp_return_value #x00000003)
                   (concat (select memcmp_return_value #x00000002)
                           (concat (select memcmp_return_value #x00000001)
                                   (select memcmp_return_value #x00000000)))))
      (a!2 (forall ((fqv Int))
             (let ((a!1 (concat (select fqv #x00000003)
                                (concat (select fqv #x00000002)
                                        (concat (select fqv #x00000001)
                                                (select fqv #x00000000))))))
               (=> (and (bvsle #x00000000 a!1) (bvslt a!1 #x00000005))
                   (= (select a a!1) (select b a!1)))))))
  (=> (= #x00000000 a!1) a!2))
```

**2.**

```
(let ((a!1 (concat (select memcmp_return_value #x00000003)
                   (concat (select memcmp_return_value #x00000002)
                           (concat (select memcmp_return_value #x00000001)
                                   (select memcmp_return_value #x00000000)))))
      (a!2 (exists ((eqv Int))
             (let ((a!1 (concat (select eqv #x00000003)
                                (concat (select eqv #x00000002)
                                        (concat (select eqv #x00000001)
                                                (select eqv #x00000000))))))
               (and (bvsle #x00000000 a!1)
                    (bvslt a!1 #x00000005)
                    (not (= (select a a!1) (select b a!1))))))))
  (=> (= #x00000001 a!1) a!2))
```

**3.**

```
(let ((a!1 (concat (select memcmp_return_value #x00000003)
                   (concat (select memcmp_return_value #x00000002)
                           (concat (select memcmp_return_value #x00000001)
                                   (select memcmp_return_value #x00000000))))))
  (= #x00000000 a!1))
```

**4.**

```
(let ((a!1 (concat (select a #x00000003)
                   (concat (select a #x00000002)
                           (concat (select a #x00000001) (select a #x00000000)))))
      (a!2 (concat (select b #x00000003)
                   (concat (select b #x00000002)
                           (concat (select b #x00000001) (select b #x00000000))))))
  (not (= a!1 a!2)))
```

Note that `memcmp_return_value` represents i, `fqv` represents the forall quantified variable, and `eqv` represents the exists quantified variable.

The returned model be Z3 is:

```
(define-fun a2 () (Array (_ BitVec 32) (_ BitVec 8))
  (_ as-array k!22))
(define-fun fqv1 () (Array (_ BitVec 32) (_ BitVec 8))
  (_ as-array k!21))
(define-fun memcmp_return_value0 () (Array (_ BitVec 32) (_ BitVec 8))
  (_ as-array k!20))
(define-fun b3 () (Array (_ BitVec 32) (_ BitVec 8))
  (_ as-array k!23))
(define-fun k!23 ((x!0 (_ BitVec 32))) (_ BitVec 8)
  (ite (= x!0 #x00000003) #x00
    #x00))
(define-fun k!20 ((x!0 (_ BitVec 32))) (_ BitVec 8)
  (ite (= x!0 #x00000000) #x00
  (ite (= x!0 #x00000002) #x00
  (ite (= x!0 #x00000001) #x00
  (ite (= x!0 #x00000003) #x00
    #x00)))))
(define-fun k!21 ((x!0 (_ BitVec 32))) (_ BitVec 8)
  (ite (= x!0 #x00000002) #x00
  (ite (= x!0 #x00000000) #x00
  (ite (= x!0 #x00000003) #x80
  (ite (= x!0 #x00000001) #x00
    #x00)))))
(define-fun k!22 ((x!0 (_ BitVec 32))) (_ BitVec 8)
  (ite (= x!0 #x00000003) #x01
    #x01))
```

Is there any problem with the Z3_ast's created? Why is this giving me SAT?

Comment: You need to post what the model z3 returns to you is. Note that `memcmp_return_value` cannot be `i`, since it's used as an array in select statements. It's gotta be something else.

Answer (score 1):

You really need to post the model speculated by z3. But it seems that what z3 is printing there doesn't match your narrative.

Take a look at (1). What's the value of `a!1`? Looks like it is the concatenation of the first 4 values in the array `mem_cmp_return_value`, in pseudo-code:

```
      memcmp_return_value[3:0]
```

this contradicts your claim that `memcmp_return_value` corresponds to `i`, since it is used clearly as an array. Ignoring that for a second, you then say:

```
  (and (bvsle #x00000000 a!1) (bvslt a!1 #x00000005))
```

which says this concatenation must be less than 5. z3 can easily pick an array where this is not true, this making (1) vacuously true.

I see similar problems in the other ones too.

Looks like your C/C++ program confused some variables there; it'd be best to be explicit with `n` is.

Long story short, impossible to answer without seeing your program that generated these constraints. But the parts you've shown us doesn't match the narrative you've given; and looks like this is indeed SAT as you're conflating the length of the array (`n`) with the concatenation of the values stored in the array itself.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed reply. Regarding the vacuously true point, I was trying to write this: `forall j s.t 0 <= j < n: a[j] = b[j]`. It seems that I did it wrong using the implication operator. How can I write this? Should I limit the domain of the quantified variable?
Regarding the concatenation point: the expression is generated by an extension of KLEE. In KLEE, according the the expressions type, the corresponding Z3_ast's are created and passed to Z3. I think they deal with 32 bit values, using concatenation of four 8 bit values or something similar.

Comment: Looks like you’re using Klee incorrectly then. Please either edit your post or ask a new question which contains the program and assertions that you feed to Klee. (And tag the question with the Klee tag so experts can chime in.) Without seeing your Klee program it’s impossible to answer your question.